# Block complete domain extension ( .to / .ru / .xyz ) referral / referral spam with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I am having a lot of referral spam in my google analytics like a lot of people do. Because this spam is coming from domains with a specific extension like .to, .ru or .xyz, I would like to block those domain extensions completely.

I searched a lot and found several .htaccess rewrite rules and applied them in several ways without result. Option 1 and 2 were placed at the end of the .htacces file. Option 3 is placed in between the #BEGIN and #END WordPress.

An example of the referral links in my analytics are:

- 12342920-1.compliance-fred.xyz
- buketeg.xyz
- bukleteg.xyz

First try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[^/]+\.xyz/? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://[^/]+\.xyz/? [NC,OR]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com [r=301,NC]
```

Second try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[^/]+\.xyz/? [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com [r=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://[^/]+\.xyz/? [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com [r=301,NC]
```

Third try:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[^/]+\.xyz/? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://[^/]+\.xyz/? [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com [r=301,NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```